# Scrapy doesn't crawl entire site

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying crawl entire site with auth system. It all works right without my auth func. When I use my auth func, scrapy login and crawl only the main page. Why it doesn't crawl all links which defined in Rules section?

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest


class TSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.net']
    start_urls = ['http:// domain.net/']
    login_page = 'http:// domain.net/login.php'

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login, dont_filter=True)


    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'login_username': 'login',
                                                'login_password': 'password'},
                                         callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a clue. I just get rid of callback in my login function ad all goes right. But does anybody explain it to me?

```
    def login(self, response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                     formdata={'login_username': 'login',
                                            'login_password': 'password'},
                                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules are only applied to the responses handled by the default callback, `parse()`.

Replace `self.parse_item` with `self.parse`, or leave the parameter out, as `parse()` is the default callback.